# Forward reverse lookups with Bind9

Tags: dns, bind9

I have a DNS server with Bind9 installed, that has IP `192.168.145.119`. This works as a resolver for a DNS server on IP `192.168.145.1`.

I have setup so it works as a forwarder when using `ping`, using `dig` etc. I have also setup a zone with CNAME's. This works **fine**, as intended. However, reverse lookups doesn't work. If I run `nslookup 192.168.145.96` I get:
`** server can't find 96.145.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN`

How can I resolve this issue?

This is my named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

options {
   directory "/var/cache/bind";
   recursion yes;
   allow-query { any; };
   allow-transfer {
    localhost;
    # Bind9 slave
    192.168.145.218;
   };

   forwarders {
      192.168.145.1;
   };
   dnssec-enable no;
   dnssec-validation false;
   auth-nxdomain no; # conform to RFC1035
   listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
include "/etc/bind/domain.conf";
```

domain.conf

```
zone "domain" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.domain";
    allow-transfer {
       192.168.145.218;
    };
    notify yes;
};
```

db.domain

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for broadcast zone
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.domain admin.domain. (
            202001161   ; Serial
            604800      ; Refresh
            86400       ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
            604800  )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;

        IN  NS  ns1.domain.
        IN  NS  ns2.domain.
ns1.domain.    IN  A   192.168.145.119
ns2.domain.    IN  A   192.168.145.218
docker-registry-vm1.domain    IN  CNAME    docker-registry-vm1.internal.
dns-master-vm1.domain.    IN  CNAME    dns-master-vm1.internal.
dns-slave-vm1.domain.    IN  CNAME    dns-slave-vm1.internal.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the configurations I had a lot of empty zones. I had to add `empty-zones-enable no;` to my `named.conf`.

Now it looks like this:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

options {
   directory "/var/cache/bind";
   recursion yes;
   allow-query { any; };
   empty-zones-enable no;
   allow-transfer {
    localhost;
    #Bind9 slave
    192.168.145.167;
   };

   forwarders {
      192.168.145.1;
   };
   dnssec-enable false;
   dnssec-validation false;
   auth-nxdomain yes; # conform to RFC1035
   listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
include "/etc/bind/domain.conf";
```